# get WM_CLASS of active window with non-ANSI letters in its title

Tags: linux, bash, xorg

trying to get WM_CLASS of active window to make AutoKey script for hotkey that works differently for different applications

here is one way to do it:

```
winname=`xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname`
winclass=`xprop -name "$winname" | grep WM_CLASS`
```

it works as desired when active window's title contains only ANSI characters.
if there are other characters (like letters of non-latin alphabets) then xprop exits with error.

is there a way around this shortcoming of xprop?

or what are other ways to get WM_CLASS or otherwise identify active window's program name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Try this:

```
winid=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
winclass=$(xprop -id "$winid" | grep WM_CLASS)
```

I tested it with Russian alphabet and it worked, but the class name will be displayed in octal numbers (e.g., for `"алфавит"` I got `"\320\260\320\273\321\204\320\260\320\262\320\270\321\202"`).

Notice I replaced the backticks, which are not recommended, by `$(...)`.

Comment: thanks, it works indeed. I guess octal encoding should not be a problem for equality test in "if" condition. why backticks are not recommended?

Comment: Mainly for clarity reasons when nesting. See this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: For your equality test, see the difference between:

`if [ "$(printf "\321\204")" = "ф" ]; then echo Equal; fi`
vs
`if [ "\321\204" = "ф" ]; then echo Equal; fi`